# What is the point of doing simulation on Markov Chain?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model, bayesian-network, markov-decision-process

I am studying Markov Chain and I am currently reading about simulation on Markov Chain but I can't see the point of simulation on Markov Chain.  What does simulation mean in Markov Chain and what can we benefit from doing it?

Comment: Simulation on Markov chains or of Markov chains. It would help if you could make the question less vague, e.g. by including quotes from the relevant textbook.

Comment: I just got this question in my head while looking simulations of Markov Chains. People explain how to do simulations of Markov Chains but don't explain the reason why we do simulation of Markov Chains. Doing simulation of Markov Chains, I am just wondering the reasons of simulations of Markov Chain?

Comment: You have to fathom why (a) a Markov chain model is a useful representation of a realistic phenomenon and (b) simulation is useful in general.